# Failure Loading Of Event Receiver Assembly

Tags: sharepoint

I have the following code snippet in my feature.xml

```
<Feature Id="0c272f81-49c0-440a-a544-677d51a8ffe4"
    ReceiverAssembly="FeaturedMasterPage, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5"
    ReceiverClass="FeaturedMasterPage.FeatureEventReciever"
    Title="Branding202" 
    Scope="Web" 
    Version="1.0.0.0" 
    Hidden="FALSE" 
    DefaultResourceFile="core" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="Branding202\Module.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Branding202\Branding202.Master" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

My FeatureEventReciever.cs says:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FeaturedMasterPage
{
    class FeatureEventReciever:SPFeatureReceiver
    {
        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                //My Code
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                //My Code
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) { }

        public override void FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) { }
    }
}
```

When i try to deploy the solution...it gives me the following error:-

> Error 1   Feature '0c272f81-49c0-440a-a544-677d51a8ffe4' could not be installed because the loading of event receiver assembly "FeaturedMasterPage, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5" failed: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'FeaturedMasterPage\, Version 1.0.0.0\, Culture\=Neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=9f4da00116c38ec5' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>   File name: 'FeaturedMasterPage\, Version 1.0.0.0\, Culture\=Neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=9f4da00116c38ec5'
>      at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(Assembly& assembly, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()

```
    0   0
```

I have already spent whole day troubleshooting this. I have installed the dll using gacutil.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's just something gone wrong in StackOverflow automatic formatting, but I don't see the "equals" sign in your assembly's full name (at the `ReceiverAssembly="...."` part).

Should be

```
FeaturedMasterPage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5
```

What I see is

```
FeaturedMasterPage, Version 1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5
```

Comment: Feature successfully deployed..

I still wonder why i have not noticed this silly mistake..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I doubt the issue is with your code but rather the path, of which only you can fix.

1. Verify your assembly name.
2. Verify your full class name.
3. Verify your assembly is getting included in the solution file.

If you get past number three then it's a SharePoint issue but judging by the errors, I can almost guarantee you that it's simply a bad reference.

Comment: yes..i was doing bad assembly reference..actually i was not putting the "eqauls" sign while referencing my GAC installed assembly in my feature.xml file. "Version 1.0.0.0,", rather it should be "Version=1.0.0.0,". I still can't believe that this silly mistake can happen to me.  The issue is resolved now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh! I had the same bug. I declared in feature.xml version as:
ReceiverAssembly="SharePointHelloWorld, Version=1.0"
And a real assembly can be at least 1.0.0.0
So, everything was registered in GAC and so on...but this feature referenced incorrect assembly version

Answer (score 0):

Can you try loading the assembly manually via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Try to **rename the Assembly** by right clicking the project name >> Properties >> from the Application tab rename both of the "**Assembly Name**" and "**Default namespace**" to be the same name. I faced this problem before and that was the solution for it. Hope it helps you.